# Lanzar comandos desde Java

Tags: java, linux, línea-de-comandos

Intento lanzar desde Java un comando en Linux con `sudo` y no encuentro la manera. He intentado lo siguiente, pero… a pesar de que desde la terminal funciona, desde la ejecución de mi programa no.

```
public Boolean activarServicio(){
    lanzarComando();
    Boolean finaly = false;
    try{
        if(!estado){
            consola2=Terminal.lanzarComando("teamviewer --daemon enable");
            //consola2=Terminal.lanzarComando("echo mipassword | sudo -S teamviewer --daemon enable");
            finaly = true;
        }
    }catch(IOException err){
    }
    return finaly;
}
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo resolver esto?

Comment: Mira este post http://felinfo.blogspot.com/2009/12/ejecutar-comandos-linux-y-ms-dos-desde.html espero pueda ayudarte

Comment: Gracias por responder. Mi codigo ejecuta perfectamente comandos sin privilegios root, el problema lo tengo con comandos con privilegios. No los ejecuta en ningún sistema que haya probado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En SO en inglés hay [dos soluciones a una pregunta equivalente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java):

La primera, sencilla pero muy desaconsejada porque expone la contraseña, es la siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash","-c","echo password| sudo -S ls"};
    Process pb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

    String line;
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();
}
```

La segunda, más segura, es editar `/etc/sudoers` con `visudo` y dar a tu usuario el permiso NOPASSWD para un script específico que realiza la tarea que necesitas:

```
nombre_de_usuario ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/mi-script.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Echa un ojo a la clase [`Runtime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html), en concreto, su método [`exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)).

Fíjate que Runtime es una clase de tipo Singleton, por lo que para usarla deberás utilizar el método estático `getRuntime()`.

A modo de ejemplo:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\mi_ruta_hacia_atom\\atom");
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Abrirá mi editor de texto.

Comment: Gracia David por contestar. Hago uso de esa estructura dentro de la clase Terminal, en el método lanzarcomando(), el problema lo tengo con comandos con privilegios. El resto de comandos funcionan correctamente

Comment: Podrias votar positivo almenos , se ah tomado el tiempo de intentar ayudar

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag Tranquilo hombre, que no me ha insultado ni nada :) si no le ha parecido útil, es totalmente normal que no me vote positivo. En cambio si te ha parecido útil a ti, te agradezco mucho que lo hagas!