# Como ejecutar un script.sh desde java con sudo?

Tags: java, bash

Necesito correr un script desde java para instalar mysql pero para que funcione necesito abrir el `.jar` como sudo desde terminal(sudo java -jar archivo.jar), de lo contrario no le pasa los permisos al `serverInstall.sh` a la hora de ejecutarlo, hay alguna manera de hacer que se ejecute desde java con los permisos sudo sin tener que correr el `archivo.jar` desde consola?

```
try {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String commands = ("scripts/serverInstall.sh");
    Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
    System.out.println("Salida serverInstall:\n");
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
                }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("ERROR Ejecutando script serverInstall.sh");
                System.out.println(ioe);

    }
```

Comment: Supongo que estás en un entorno linux. Puedes leerte esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/98780/33391

Comment: ya probaste? ´sudo /pathjava/bin/java -classpath $tujar com.tupaqueteprincipal.TuClaseConMainJava´